# best t-sql for providing nth page in showing data?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, tableadapter

I want to item 1 to 50 in my first page by using

```
SELECT TOP(50) * 
FROM Items_table
```

and it works fine but how can I get second 50 items for next page? How should be the query be?

Please note that I can't use `LIMIT` because I am using SQL Server.

I have also problem with queries like:

```
select * 
from (
    select 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (
            ORDER BY date_of_creation desc, time_of_creation desc) AS Row2,
        * 
    from 
        Items_table) ir
where 
    ir.Row2 between @start and @end
```

The problem is in this condition table adapter doesn't support `OVER`.

Is there any other t-sql code that table adapter support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I've achieved that with this query in table adapters:</s>

```
select top (@count) * 
from Items_table
where id not in (select top(@count2) id from Items_table)
order by Date_Of_Creation desc,Time_Of_Creation desc
```

Thanks for participating.

Update: Please don't use that either with ordering right in inner query because I had repeated results and some bugs. In addition when you want load 10th page the performance of query will be bad (The time needed to execute query is not acceptable).

Instead I was forced to use this method (and it is good also):

```
Select TOP (@count) from Item_table
order by Date_Of_Creation desc,Time_Of_Creation desc
```

Then each page should contain some of the rows of this query(If you are going to use multi page).

If you have one page that when user reaches bottom you want to load more, in this method you should execute this query every time you want to load more with bigger @count and load the items in the page.

Comment: If that worked it was by luck.  select top(@count2) id from Items_table is arbitrary rows

Comment: You need to add the same order by statement from the outer query to the inner query. Or as Blam mentioned, you might get the results correct only by sheer luck. So it may work now, but it won't always work.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have added an update to the answer and used different method since first one had bugs and performance issues

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or above, then this will help you

```
DECLARE @RowsPerPage INT = 50; 
DECLARE @PageNumber INT = 2; 

SELECT *
FROM ItemsTable
ORDER BY date_of_creation desc, time_of_creation desc
OFFSET (@PageNumber - 1) * @RowsPerPage ROWS
FETCH NEXT @RowsPerPage ROWS ONLY
```

Variable `@PageNumber` specifies the page that you want to retrieve (first, second ..etc)

Comment: It works in ssms but tableadapter doesn't recognize it as parameters!

Comment: I never worked with tableadapter but you can start your query from the select and replace the PageNumber and the RowsPerPage with the actual numbers defined at the top if this is the parameters you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna code in sql 2008 try this:

```
    Drop Table T1 ;
GO
Create Table T1( id int, Title varchar(100) );
Insert T1 Values
( 1000, 'A1000' ),( 1001, 'A1001' ),( 1002, 'A1002' ),( 1003, 'A1003' ),( 1004, 'A1004' ),
( 1005, 'A1005' ),( 1006, 'A1006' ),( 1007, 'A1007' ),( 1008, 'A1008' ),( 1009, 'A1009' ),
( 1010, 'A1010' ),( 1011, 'A1011' ),( 1012, 'A1012' ),( 1013, 'A1013' ),( 1014, 'A1014' ),
( 1015, 'A1015' ),( 1016, 'A1016' ),( 1017, 'A1017' ),( 1018, 'A1018' ),( 1019, 'A1019' );
GO


Declare @PageNO int =1, @RowsPerPage int =5;
Select Rw,Id, Title FROM
(
    Select 
        Rw=Row_number() Over( order by Id ) , Id, Title 
    from T1
) A
where Rw between (@PageNO-1)*@RowsPerPage+1 and @PageNO*@RowsPerPage
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem is we cannot use declaration in table adapters

Comment: You dont need to declare variable. They can be the list og  parameters in a procedure or function.

Comment: Yes if I use stored procedure the problem is solved but with tableadapter query it isn't because it doesn't accept parameters in this mode. Thanks anyway, I used the query in the answered post.